# Is it possible to have two build.gradle files?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

Sorry if this is a stupid question BUT....I gotta think theres a better way to do this.

Basically I have two "environments" for my spring boot API. One is on my local machine where I use the in built Jetty server and the other is a digitalocean box with tomcat.

Whenever I want to build my war file I have to go into my build file and uncomment out the following

```
apply plugin: "war"
```

and the dependancy

```
dependencies {
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
....
}
```

Is there away I can have a second build file kind of like how I have application-local.yml vs application-production.yml OR even better would be a way to not comment those values out when I want to run locally.

In case it matters I'm using Intellij.

Thanks for your time!!

*Slight edit*

So just to shed more light. From my IDE when I want to build my war file I do gradle build with the apply war plugin and tomcat dependancy enabled. However if I leave these enabled and try to run my application in the IDE it wont start and will fire an exception:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-22 22:49:53.628 ERROR 62008 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.terrabyte.DevlyAuthServiceApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:336)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:285)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:569)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
    at com.terrabyte.DevlyAuthServiceApplication.main(DevlyAuthServiceApplication.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:403)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:326)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3d4eac69]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:455)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:151)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3244)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2387)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 24 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Never used Gradle but I am pretty sure that it has profiles. You can have `dev` and `prod` as two profiles and specify your goals accordingly.

Comment: Ok cool thanks @AniketSahrawat I'll have a google for that and see so! Didnt even think of profiles for gradle

Comment: Yup ok this seems to be what I need. Cant believe I never thought to google Gradle Profiles before :-d Many thanks @AniketSahrawat (If you want to put this as an answer I'll mark it as the right one).

Comment: Don't worry about writing an answer because I believe that this post is already a duplicate of many others and my answer won't have any meaningful contribution to the site. But I am glad I could help you out.

Comment: Well...thank you very much! You really did help!! Take care out there!